# Using an external monitor on an LG R590 laptop

Tags: 10.04, xorg, laptop, monitor

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my LG R590 laptop, and when I boot it, I can't get my external monitor to work. System->Preferences->Monitors won't recognize it (even when I click `Detect monitors`), and when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> - which is my laptop's function key for switching between built-in/external displays - it does nothing.

I found in the internet [this article](http://sernaonubuntu.wikidot.com/multiple-monitors), which says I need to edit my `xorg.conf` file for this to work, and says that file should be created automatically when I install Ubuntu. However, I can't find it in my `/etc/X11/`, and [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/141802/where-is-xorg-conf-in-ubuntu-10-04) says that Ubuntu doesn't need that file anymore so it doesn't create it - though it still uses it if it finds one. It also says that if I have an NVidia card (which I have) I can force Ubuntu to create it by using `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, but I get a `command not found` when I try it.

So, is there any other way to make Ubuntu recognize my external screen? Or any way to force Ubuntu to create a `xorg.conf` file so I can edit it according to that tutorial?

BTW, I don't know if it matters, but I connect my external monitor via HDMI-DVI cable(HDMI side goes in my laptop, DVI side goes the monitor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve this all by myself(with some help from the Internet... and a friend who knows some Linux...)

I just had to download and install [the NVidia driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html), reboot, and than `System->Preferences->Monitors` will open the NVidia's control panel instead of the default Ubuntu one, and allow me to set everything I need plus it made me an xorg.conf file.

Now the only problem left is how to make it work in terminal mode...